# How to save an image to directory after resize in php?

Tags: php, gd

I am using the GD libary in php to resize uploaded images which works fine but I just can't figure out how to save the resized image to a directory. How do I go about this? I don't seem to get any errors.

```
   <?php
    // The file
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $filename = 'test.jpg';
    $percent = 0.5;


    if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
            {

    $filename = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];

    // Content type
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    // Get new dimensions
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $new_width = $width * $percent;
    $new_height = $height * $percent;

    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);

    //This is my attempt to save the image that does not work
 if (move_uploaded_file($image, "memberFiles/saved_image.jpg")) {
}
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
imagejpeg($image_p, 'some/other/existing/directory/result.jpg');
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you